# Changing user-agent on puppeteer-extra doesn't seem to take affect

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, chromium, user-agent

I'm trying to scrape different websites using puppeteer. As I'm using [puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) for that (for their [stealth-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)), I've decided to use their [anonymize-ua plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua) to randomly change the default user-agent to further reduce detection.

I tried following their explanation, but when I'm logging the browser's actual user-agent it seems to didn't take affect.

Attached below is an example for what I'm doing:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import UserAgent from 'user-agents';

const scrape = async (url: string) => {
    // Set stealth plugin
    const stealthPlugin = StealthPlugin();
    puppeteer.use(stealthPlugin);

    // Create random user-agent to be set through plugin
    const userAgent = new UserAgent({ platform: 'MacIntel', deviceCategory: 'desktop' });
    const userAgentStr = userAgent.toString();
    console.log(`User Agent: ${userAgentStr}`);

    const anonymizeUserAgentPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua')({
        customFn: () => userAgentStr 
    });
    puppeteer.use(anonymizeUserAgentPlugin);

    puppeteer
        .launch({ headless: false })
        .then(async (browser) => {
            // Different from the one above
            console.log(`User Agent: ${await browser.userAgent()}`);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Although the first user-agent string is randomized (from run to run) through [user-agents library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-agents), the other one logged when creating the browser is the actual running Chromium version.

Am I missing some configuration? or shouldn't I be looking at the browser user-agent like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging inside [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra), and the anonymize-ua plugin code, I've found out:

1. The user-agent is changed on the `page` instance, so trying to look at the one coming from the `browser` will not result in the actual one used. The right way is to log `navigator.useragent` through the devtools console.
2. There's an open issue on puppeteer that events are not triggered early enough for listeners (e.g. plugins using `onPageCreated`) to be able to modify the page instance (e.g. user-agent) before the browser request occurs. It seems that they tried to workaround it by first `goto` *about:blank*. This workaround did not solve it for me, because the user-agent was not changed.

So my solution was to duplicate the code from the plugin and set the generated user-agent on the `page`:

```js
puppeteer
    .launch({ headless: false })
    .then(async (browser) => {
        browser
            .pages()
            .then(async ([page]) => {
                await page.setUserAgent(userAgentStr);
            })
            .catch(async (e) => {
                console.log(e);
                await browser.close();
            });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Hopes this helps anyone!

Comment: This code could be simpler without the `.then`s. Why not use `async`/`await` only?

Answer (score 2):

By default '**puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua**' is set with property `makeWindows: true` which overrides your platform settings 'MacIntel' with 'Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64'

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import UserAgent from 'user-agents';

const scrape = async (url: string) => {
    // Set stealth plugin
    const stealthPlugin = StealthPlugin();
    puppeteer.use(stealthPlugin);

    // Create random user-agent to be set through plugin
    const userAgent = new UserAgent({ platform: 'MacIntel', deviceCategory: 'desktop' });
    const userAgentStr = userAgent.toString();
    console.log(`User Agent: ${userAgentStr}`);

    const anonymizeUserAgentPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua')({
        customFn: () => userAgentStr,
        stripHeadless: true,
        makeWindows: false,
    });
    puppeteer.use(anonymizeUserAgentPlugin);

    puppeteer
        .launch({ headless: false })
        .then(async (browser) => {
            // Different from the one above
            console.log(`User Agent: ${await browser.userAgent()}`);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Set the **makeWindows** to **false** as in example below and issue should be fixed.

I'm attaching a link to the repository to the specific line of code that solves this
https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/blob/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua/index.js#L47